# given a permutation, whats the probability that the circle $|c_1| = k$ for some $k \in N$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

let $\sigma \in S_n$ be a permutation from [n] $\to$ [n], we shell define the circle $c_1 \ to \ be\ (1 \ x_1 \ x_2 \ ... \ x_{k-1}) $ when $ 
\sigma (1) = x_1 , \ and \ \forall i \in ${1 , ... ,k-2}$ 
\ \sigma (x_i) = x_{i+1} \ and \ \sigma(x_{k-1}) = 1.
$
means that we can write $c_1  \ as: \ 1\to x_1 \to x_2 \to ... \to x_{k-1} \to 1 $
and also $|c_1| = k$.

Now given arbitrary permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ in uniform probability space, whats the probability that for $ 0 < k < n+1 : \ |c_1| = k$.

now i believe that for any k as such the probability is $\frac{1}{n}$.
we can see that the probability for $|c_1| = 1$ is $\frac{(n-1)!}{n!} = \frac{1}{n}$ as we wished for.
can someone please explain me why is that true for every k between 1 and n or show me the full prove.

Comment: Perhaps $c_1$ is a cycle and not a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's count the number of permutations, shall we? :)
We have $n-1$ choices for $x_1$, the image of $1$, as we can't have $x_1 = 1$.
Now, we have $n-2$ choices for $x_2$, as it can neither be $x_1$ nor $1$.
This goes on, giving us $n-i$ choices for $x_i$ and thus
$$\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!}$$ 
choices in total.
Now there are $n-k$ points left that can be mapped in any way, giving us $(n-k)!$ possible ways.
In total, we have 
$$\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!} (n-k)!$$
permutations where the cycle containing $1$ has length $k$.

I'm sure you can now do the rest. :)

Answer (score 0):

For $i=1,\dots,k$ let $E_{i}$ denote the event that $\left\{ 1,x_{1},\dots,x_{i-1}\right\} $
has $i$ elements and note that $P\left(E_{1}\right)=1$.

Under condition $E_{i-1}$ the event $E_{i}$ will occur if and only
if $x_{i-1}$ - which will have its value in $\left\{ 1,\dots,n\right\} \setminus\left\{ x_{1},\dots,x_{i-2}\right\} $ - 
will **not** have value $1$.

That gives conditional probability $P\left(E_{i}\mid E_{i-1}\right)=\frac{n-i+1}{n-i+2}$ and we can calculate:

$$P\left(E_{k}\right)=P\left(E_{1}\cap E_{2}\cap E_{3}\cap\cdots\cap E_{k}\right)=$$$$P\left(E_{1}\right)P\left(E_{2}\mid E_{1}\right)P\left(E_{3}\mid E_{2}\right)\cdots P\left(E_{k}\mid E_{k-1}\right)=$$$$1\cdot\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-2}{n-1}\cdots\frac{n-k+1}{n-k+2}=\frac{n-k+1}{n}$$

Then: $$P(|c_1|=k)=P\left(x_{k}=1\wedge E_{k}\right)=P\left(x_{k}=1\mid E_{k}\right)P\left(E_{k}\right)=\frac{1}{n-k+1}\frac{n-k+1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}$$